# sharing variables in a multi-project solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I'm creating a solution in VS2010 for Outlook 2010 using C# that is comprised of 3 projects.

- Project A - B & C are dependent on this one.  It defines certain variables/functions that need to be accessible from B & C
- Project B - Needs to read variables from A.
- Project C - Needs to read variables from A

I've not gotten far, yet, as I can't seem to read the variables from A into B or C.  I've added A as a reference to both B & C, but assigning a local variable in one of those to the value from A results only in a null (which I know is not true).

More clarification:

This is a set of 3 outlook add-ins.

- Add-in A of the project (on which the others are dependent) calls certain functions and pulls information into [variables](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/variables/) that will be needed by B & C
- B & C comprise of a completely set of functions that are each depending on the information gleaned by A.  This information needs to be the same for both B & C at all times.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing that would prevent project C from reading A and Bs variables except access modifiers (internal/private/protected vs. public). The variables from A are indeed null. There is no other possibility. Most likely your code is not assigning the values to the variables of A before you use them. Where/when do the values in A get assigned?

Comment: "reading variables" is a sure sign that you don't understand object-oriented programming. If you give more details on what you're trying to accomplish (as opposed to _how_ you thing you should accomplish it), then you may get some good advice.

Comment: A word of clarification. The variables are separate for each process.  So if you run B, and it sets a variable in A, and then run C in separate process, then it will not be able to read the value that was set by B.  Instead, it will have it's own set of values for variables completely independent of the values from the other process. This hold true even if you run the same executable twice.  Unless you provide some more complex mechanisms for inter-process communication, but processes will not affect each other.

Comment: @John - I have an understanding of OOP, but having been out of the programming world for about 15 years and then thrust back into it last year, I'm still regaining my skills.  I can give details, but saying it's a "sure sign" that I do not understand is not constructive.

Comment: @John - not everyone is an expert programmer, and with many other tasks at my job beyond programming, I don't have the time to learn every aspect of C# when my base programming was C++ over 15 years ago.

Comment: @Larry: again, it's an OOP thing, not a C++ vs. C# thing. How would you have done this in C++? Surely you wouldn't have exposed fields of a class as public so that an instance of another class could set them at random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to past some code.  But anyway, ensure that project A is a class library.  It should be as simple as:

**Project A**

```
namespace A
{
     public class AClass  // note, this is **public**
     {
         // ctor
         public AClass { }
         public void AMethod { }
     } 
}
```

**Project B** (has A as a reference)

```
using A;

namespace B
{
     public class BClass
     {
         // don't actually need "A" qualifier here as we're "using A" above, this is just for clarity
         private A.AClass aClass_ = new A.AClass();

         // ctor
         public BClass()
         {
             aClass_.AMethod();
         }
     }
}
```

You'd have something similar in project **C**.

Comment: Here's a question...I"m writing this as an Outlook add-in, and some of these variables in A need to be initialized on startup.  Should I NOT write A as an add-in as I currently am doing?

Comment: If A is a just a class library then no, it should not be an add-in.  If B & C are the actual add-ins, then yes.  And they can use the A class library.

Comment: so, even though my information needs to be the same for B & C at all times, you're saying it would be easier to instantiate a class that gets called each time I need the information?  What happens when B & C get out of sync?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to achieve.  These are design decisions.  My answer is here to show how to share a common class library amongst projects.  What you do with it, is up to you :)

Comment: I appreciate it.  I'll see what I can tackle with this information in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Always insure that Public methods, properties, fields, etc. names indicate a distinct context to avoid usage and maintenance confusion.

For example, a single solution having dozens of projects should not have identically named properties:

Project A: public int ThisValue{get;set;} -> ProjAThisValue
Project B: public int ThisValue{get;set;} -> ProjBThisValue

Failing to do so creates referencing nightmares.